# AS3 Does Loader ProgressEvent.PROGRESS event guarantee that server received the request?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new to Action Script and I've faced the following code:

```
var lc: LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
lc.checkPolicyFile = false;
lc.allowCodeImport = false;

var ldr: Loader = new Loader();
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadHandler);
ldr.load(new URLRequest(url), lc);
```

Does `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` event guarantee that server received the request? Can I asume in `loadHandler` that request has been received or should I use

```
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadHandler);
```

instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's indicated in its [definition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ProgressEvent.html) :

> A ProgressEvent object is dispatched when a load operation has begun or a socket has received data ...

So yes, when the `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` event is fired, you are sure that your server has received the request.

And about `Event.COMPLETE` event, it's fired when the load operation has been completed so you can use your loaded content.

Hope that can help.